# Is there a way to reset a Fragment Tab back to the parent view on click of the tab

Tags: java, android

I have a FragmentTabHost that has 3 tabs (A,  B, C). I am using a single fragment (with a listview) to populate each tab — but the listview has different data based on the selected tab.

From the listview, you can click an item to go to a list view item details fragment.

If I’m on a details fragment, I want to be able to click the tab again and it resets back to the listview and out of the details fragment.

Is this possible? Someone please help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I use this library for maintaing fragment stacks
https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav

Answer (score 0):

You should implement OnTabSelectedListener. here is a code sample:

```
 tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new 
 TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        //do stuff here
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

[OnTabSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener)

There is onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) method. On this method just pop fragment from backstack.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

**Must**: When going to details fragment from list fragment, you must add fragment to back stack.

Comment: Would I add this to the FragmentTabHost or the actual Fragment that holds the listview? Also, I know this is another question not related, but is it possible to completely navigate out of the FragmentTabHost on click of the listview item (so I don't even see the tabs)? Apologies for the slightly different question, but your input will be much appreciated. Re: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56465689/hide-fragment-tab-host-tabs-within-the-child-fragments

Comment: You should add onTabSelectedListener to tablayout. See my edited answer. And regarding your another question, Yes you can. You can start a new activity from listview item click with startActivity() method. And in that activity you can add the details fragment.

Comment: You can play with the 3 call backs events. OnTabSelected called when new tab selected, onTabReselected called when current tab is selected again by clicking tab navigation(this one you need), onTabUnselected called when you select another tab.

Comment: Thank you! Tried the solution but I couldn't figure it out because I am using TabHost and not TabLayout :(